# ActiveStorage blob removed after attachment file changed, how to handle the situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

**Scenario Background:**

Model Image has_one_attached image file, we get the image url through `url_for`

**Actions**

1. updated new image file
2. access to old image URL
3. get 404 error

**Discussion**

404 error is as expected, as the old image was removed. What I am wondering is if I can access the newly uploaded image's static URL? Or are there any recommendations regarding this scenario?

**EDIT 2019/10/5**

What I encountered is some service like linkedIn, slack, will cache the page and it's image's URL. But that URL will be invalid after new images uploaded. So my thoughts would be

1. **do not remove old activestorage record**: this is more like a workaround but actually I can't find this option in activestorage
2. **just get image's static URL instead of using `url_for` to bypass rails and related 404 activestorage record not found**: cannot found related methods either

Comment: What I am wondering is if I can access to the newly uploaded image URL? `url_for(thing.attachment)`. Or what is it that you are asking that you can just figure out by [reading the guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-one-attached)?

Comment: I think you are stuck because the links are cached in user's browsers? Should have used expiring URLs in the first place. Can do easily with S3, not sure about others.

Comment: @max I've updated my original post since it was not clear enough, I was trying to get the "static url" of the image instead of `url_for`. The updated post also provides additional context, hope that helps.

Comment: @Nerve Your guess is right. But if the URL is changing after a new image update, how can the expiring URLs help?